# Forward a method as a delegate with arguments

Tags: c#, delegates

I have the following problem.

```
class A
{
    public bool Execute(int a);
}

class B
{
    public bool Execute(bool a);
}


static class Consumer
{
    public bool Validate(Delegate d);
}
```

I would like to to be able to Call  the Consumer's Validate method from inside the "A" and "B" Classes with the execute method as an argument

Inside A or B :

```
public static main()
{
    x = new A()
    x1 = A.Execute(1);

    y = new B()
    y1 = B.Execute(true)

    Consumer.Validate(x1)
    Consumer.Validate(y1)
}
```

Of course this could work, but it would not do what I want it to. It would Execute and create a bool value X1 and not store it as a delegete to be executed at a certain point I Choose or to stre it as as internal object i a collection and then reExecute it.

I hope I got it over to you so you can understand my intentions.

But how to forward it with the argumets.

This is simplified explanation of the problem, but still the same.

Is it possible to pack the arguments with the methods delegate  in the consumer, and then just execute them.

Comment: it's not clear what you want to achieve by validate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use lambda

```
public bool Execute(int a)
{
    Consumer.Validate(() => this.Execute(a));
}
```

The lambda `() => this.Execute(a)` will store the value of `a` inside itself and provide to Validate simple you-should-know-nothing interface.

And better change the signature of `Validate` to:

```
 public bool Validate(Func<bool> paramLessPredicate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need both delegate and value as arguments in the Consumer.Validate function:

```
public bool Validate<T>(Funct<T,bool> validator, T value)
{
    bool validatorResult = validator(value);
    // Do whatever..
    return someBool;
}
```

And in A:

```
int value = 10;
bool result = Consumer.Validate(Execute, value);
```

Comment: I would have to make foe every class a custom Validate function. I want to avoid this.